How to disable mouse acceleration through powershell
I have recently gotten a mouse for my laptop, though the mouse acceleration is really bugging me. Since this is a managed school device, I do not have access to any elevated prompts, settings app, control panel, device manager, cmd prompt, or regedit, but I do have access to Powershell.  I use my trackpad a lot too, so I would prefer if mouse acceleration were switching on and off depending on if my mouse was in use. Any help is appreciated!
I've taken a look online and saw solutions that used C++ to interact with the Windows API, but I wasn't fully sure what I would need to do that, especially due to the fact that upon looking it up, it would require admin privileges in some scenarios, while being available to base users in other scenarios

To disable mouse acceleration using PowerShell, you can use the following script. This script changes the registry settings to disable mouse acceleration:

Open Notepad and paste the following code:

New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Mouse" -Name "MouseSpeed" -Value "0" -PropertyType String -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Mouse" -Name "MouseThreshold1" -Value "0" -PropertyType String -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Mouse" -Name "MouseThreshold2" -Value "0" -PropertyType String -Force


Save the file with a .ps1 extension, for example, DisableMouseAcceleration.ps1.

Run PowerShell as an administrator and execute the saved script by typing:


.\DisableMouseAcceleration.ps1

This script will set the values of MouseSpeed, MouseThreshold1, and MouseThreshold2 to 0, which will disable mouse acceleration.

Will this affect my trackpad too, or just my physical mouse?

Changing the registry settings via a PowerShell script will affect all pointing devices that use those settings, including both the mouse and the trackpad. If you want to disable acceleration for just the mouse and not the trackpad, unfortunately there's no direct way to separate those settings in Windows.
